# What is the best way of uploading files in asp mvc 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I want to make an upload controller fo my asp mvc Application but there are many ways to do this:

- [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) (jQuery)
- a [form](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) inside your view
- with [Html.BeginForm](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Implementing_HTTP_File_Up.aspx)
- probably many other methods I haven't found yet

But I was wondering: what is the best and what is the easiest way to upload a file in asp mvc?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [easiest way](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx). A plain html form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and a controller action taking a [HttpPostedFileBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx) as argument.

Later if you want to get funky you could enhance it with some flash upload controls and jquery stuff and even support drag and drop from your desktop through HTML5. But the basic bare bone is a plain HTML `<form>` with `input type="file"` elements.

Remember that no matter what technique you decide always make sure to provide a fallback scenario with the basic stuff (the same way gmail does it) so that for example users sitting behind corporate firewalls or with Flash disabled would still be able to use your site. That's the only method that's guaranteed to work.

Comment: Could you give an example cause I tried it but when it posted the file had the value null?

Comment: @Myst3ric, I don't think that I can give you a better example than what's already in the [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) that I linked in my answer. Make sure that the name of your file input field is the same as your action argument.